# Loading data into model by id-Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

im trying to use direct store in Extjs
heres the code to my store

```
Ext.define('IDE.store.Files', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    proxy: {
        type: 'direct',
        api: {
            create:Files.AddNew,
            read:Files.GetFile,
            update:Files.Update,
            destroy:Files.Delete,
            //load:Files.GetFile
        },
        paramOrder:'Path'
    },
    model:'IDE.model.File'
})
```

the code for model is

```
Ext.define('IDE.model.File', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'Path', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Extention', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Content', type: 'string' }
    ],
    idProperty:'Path',
    store:'IDE.store.Files'
})
```

as you can see the `idProperty` is `Path`
the following code segment is giving error

```
//this.getStore('IDE.store.Files').load(path, { sucess: function (file) {
//                console.log(file.get('Content'));           
//            } });
this.getStore('IDE.store.Files').load(path);
```

here im getting `path` from somewhere and trying to load a file from the particular path
the error is

```
 Ext.data.proxy.Direct.doRequest(): No direct function specified for this proxy
```

now the problem is that documentation of extjs isnt enough and everywhere i searched i could only see 4 api in the `api` object of `proxy`.
Which are 
1.create
2.read
3.update
4.destroy
which api am i missing ? OR 
where do i need to give a direct function for `load()`

Comment: Which version of ExtJS exactly are you using? Because the parameters you give to load() seem to be incorrect. Also, can remove the load: config from the api: - it isn't supported.

Comment: ooops that was because i was trying something.. now i have edited the question to reflect the exact situation

Comment: Which version on EXT? 4.0.7? 4.1?

Comment: Although I think it is the problem, I believe the correct load() parameters should look like so: this.getStore('IDE.store.Files').load( { params: {path: 'somepath' } } ). Can you confirm this still doesn't work?

Comment: I think the reason for this is that ExtJS looks for the proxy in the model. Pretty sure your code will work with 4.1. Anyway, could you please try to move the proxy definition to the model and see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple problems that i could figure out with my code so just putting here for help of community.
1. the way i was calling the load function is correct.. and it just doest takes the parameter but a whole object with scope and callback so mayb that was the error saying
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load
2. if i just remove the `api`.. and use the `directFn` config option then it appears to work..

**Code:**

```
Ext.define('IDE.store.Files', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    proxy: {
        type: 'direct',
        directFn: Files.GetFile, // <--- new line of code
        api: {
            create:Files.AddNew,
            //read:Files.GetFile, // <--- old line of code
            update:Files.Update,
            destroy:Files.Delete
        },
        paramOrder:'Path'
    },
    model:'IDE.model.File'
})
```

Comment: I added the code so the next reader can see what the code looks like.